# How to save login credentials on app build in Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, userdefaults

I have been experiencing extreme difficulties finding out a way to save users login information on my build (hours and hours of researching). I have tried to implement UserDefaults and Core Data, but I have already created the login/sign up views with other integrated lines of code and can't figure out the correct place to put these other lines of code(UserDefaults/CoreData) without receiving errors/ or interfering with other actions. I am a beginner and any input would be fantastic!

this is an example of my login `ViewController` :

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordfield: UITextField!

    var actInd : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.actInd.center = self.view.center
        self.actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
        self.actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray

        view.addSubview(self.actInd)
        emailfield.delegate = self
        passwordfield.delegate = self
        super.viewDidLoad()

        emailfield.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Username:",
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])

        passwordfield.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password:",
        attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        if textField == emailfield {
            passwordfield.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else if textField == passwordfield {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        return true
```

Comment: The likeliest way to get a useful answer here is to show what code you've written and explain what issues you're having with it.  It's very difficult to give a specific answer to a general question.

Comment: Thank you, I have just added the start of my login ViewController. Hopefully this well help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be the place where you use the username/password to make the actual login request. That's the place you'll have the complete info and just save it to the `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: thank you for your input. I'm still confused on where exactly I implement that at?

Comment: do you have a method to get the username and password from the textField and make the network request? You can save it when you receive the success response from the server

Comment: no I do not this is what I'm really trying to figure out. That does make perfect sense though.

Comment: So what I usually do is I'll make a submit button, make it disable first,  listen to the `UIControlEvents.EditingChanged` notification, and in the method you pass in as the selector check if the username and password field is empty or not, if both of them are not empty enable the submit button. Then in the tap action of the submit button you can make the request and save the credentials.

Comment: okay great thats exactly what im looking for! is there anyway you can show an example line of code for me?